# How would I use React Hook UseEffect in order to create a function with searchMovies and searchTitles?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

This is code for the interface

```
export interface ActorAttributes {
    TYPE?: string,
    NAME?: string,
}

export interface MovieAttributes {
    OBJECTID: number,
    SID: string,
    NAME: string,
    DIRECTOR: string,
    DESCRIP: string,
}
```

This is the code for my App.tsx

```
import { searchMovies, searchActors, MovieAttributes, ActorAttributes } from "@utils/atts"

const Home: React.FC = () => {
    const [search, setSearch] = React.useState(false)
    const [movieSearch, setMovieSearch] = React.useState<MovieAttributes[]>([]);
    const [actorSearch, setActorSearch] = React.useState<ActorAttributes>([]);


const demo = async () => { 
        setSearch(true)
        const demoMovieSearch = await searchMovies("Dumbo")
        setMovieSearch(demoMovieSearch)
        console.log("Movie example", demoMovieSearch)

        const demoActorSearch = await searchActors("j", demoDistrictSearch[1].SID)
        setActorSearch(demoActorSearch)
        console.log("Actor Example", demoActorSearch)
        setSearching(false)
    }
```

This is what I've tried so far with useEffect. My goal is to implement a search bar function by using useEffect. I apologize in advance if there are errors within my code as I am fairly new to react. If anyone has any tips, ideas, suggestions, etc. please feel free to leave a comment.

```
useEffect(() => {
        demo()
    }, [])
```

Comment: *How would I use React Hook UseEffect in order to create a function with searchMovies and searchTitles?* - you don't, just search the data on click

Comment: Why do you *specifically* want to use `useEffect`?  What are you trying to achieve with it?  In what way does your attempt fail?